# What's the meaning of "innate of arrogance"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What's the correct meaning of "innate of arrogance" in this example? I know "innate" more or less means "existing since birth", so I feel it may be "rising/coming from a place of arrogance" or more literally "being born out of arrogance".

> Are you really arrogant/conceited/self-important/self-righteous, or do you often display a “haughty” behaviour **innate of something else** than arrogance, that on first glance appears to be **innate of arrogance**? [source](https://www.quora.com/Why-am-I-so-self-conceited-arrogant/answer/Sophie-Dockx?srid=uFWc8)

Comment: innate of arrogance is wrong: innate is an adjective; not a noun.

Comment: Your interpretation that the author probably intended "arising from arrogance", but as Lambie says the construction "innate of" is awkward and unidiomatic. Maybe the author took "born of" and tried to make it sound more sophisticated, but whatever the case, it's ear-bending.

Comment: @Lambie - So??  "Behavior *typical* of pink Martians" is perfectly legal (if prejudiced) syntax, and "typical" is an adjective.

Comment: In the above passage I would interpret "innate of" to mean "derived from".  I agree that it's a somewhat awkward wording, but not anything that your average reasonably-educated native English speaker would have trouble deciphering.

Comment: @Hot Licks /do you often display a “haughty” behaviour innate of something else than arrogance/ is the sentence.  I guess we don't speak the same English. That is completely non-idiomatic.

Comment: I'm sure the writer intended *behaviour innate of X* to mean *...arising from X*, as pointed out by others. But the primary "meaning" I take from it is that (a) this writer isn't very good, and (b) he's making a futile effort to appear more articulate than he actually *is*.

Comment: @Lambie - I agree that the wording is awkward, but the fact that "innate" is an adjective has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It didn't even cross my mind that this sentence could be wrong, looks so sophisticated, haha. Thank you all!

Comment: @Hot Licks Whatever. Find some other way of saying it. GENERALLY speaking, in English an adjective is pre-positioned and very few post-positioned ones allow OF. I see no way to see what the "the writer" "intended". I think "the author" is a fake. Some Search Engine Optimization fool,.

Comment: @Lambie, wow, are you saying I'm fake?

Comment: @bah Are you the writer??? No, "I" am not saying "you" are a fake. But if you are the writer, it is not properly written. There are a lot of people writing SEO articles and yes, they are fakes. Fake writers, not real writers in the sense of being good writers.

Comment: I'm not "the writer", but I'm "the author" of this question. :) Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you often display a “haughty” behaviour innate of something else than arrogance, that on first glance appears to be innate of arrogance?

a little better:

> Do you often display a “haughty” behaviour innate of something other than arrogance, that on first glance appears to be innate of arrogance?

This horribly written sentence means:

> Do you often display a haughty behaviour which does not actually arise from arrogance, even though at first glance it would seem to?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase 'innate of arrogance' is confusing because it is faulty grammar. You use 'to' with 'innate'. Assuming you're using 'innate' to mean an adjective for 'something essentially a part of', then

> *'innate of NP'

is not used for that in the major standard varieties of English (AmE, BrE, AusE, etc). [The common collocation for 'innate' is 'to'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=innate+to%2C+innate+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=):

> Such behavior is **innate to** this breed of dogs

As to the meaning of that passage, given the context, the intention of the paragraph is to distinguish between essential properties of arrogance and properties of arrogance that might be shared with other personality traits. For example, if someone might act in a assuming manner out of actual authority rather than over-confident arrogance.